# CSS Transforms - Mirroring for Right to Left Version

Tags: jquery, css, transform

http://jsfiddle.net/uy57B/2/

```
.left li {
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(25deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(25deg);
    -o-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(25deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(25deg);
    transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(25deg);
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.left li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);  
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.right li {
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(-25deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(-25deg);
    -o-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(-25deg);
    transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(-25deg);
     margin-right:-20px;
}
.right li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective( 350px ) rotateY(0deg);  
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Left works PERFECTLY, just can't get the "right" stack to mirror the left exactly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/uy57B/5/

you need to apply the margin only at the last element of the list on the right!

```
.right li:last-child:hover {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```